# Wondering if the two sentences I made are correct grammatically

Tags: grammar

1. I'll make it office around 11:30 . 
   ( this is a promice meaning that I will arrive / I will show up around 11:30 in/at the office. )

..............

1. He wouldn't have jumped down your throat if you had not made it office late.

I am sure they seem wordy. But I need to know if my perception of the similar text have been read today is correct or not.

Comment: We say that you make it **to the** office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"make it", as a synonym for "arrive", cannot take a direct object (as you have written in *I'll make it office*); you must specify your destination with a prepositional phrase:

> I'll make it to the office ...

Other than needing that "to the" in both of your sentences, they seem fine.